# Expressjs Mongoose find nested embedded documents are undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm building a game with [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) 0.6.18 [expressjs](http://expressjs.com/) 2.5.8 and [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) 2.6.7.

I'm trying to store and retrieve embedded documents with mongoose.
Consider this example :

**User schema**

```
var User = module.exports = new Schema({
      username: { type: String }
    , characters: [Character]
    , created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**Character schema**

```
var Character = module.exports = new Schema({
      name: { type: String }
    , spells: [Spell]
    , created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**Spell schema**

```
var Spell = module.exports = new Schema({
      name: { type: String }
    , created { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

**Mongoose**

```
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost/mygame');
mongoose.model('User', require('./models/user'));
mongoose.model('Character', require('./models/character'));
mongoose.model('Spell', require('./models/spell')
```

**Route**

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var User = db.model('User')
    , Character = db.model('Character')
    , Spell = db.model('Spell')
    , u = new User({username:'foo'})
    , c = new Character({name:'bar'});

  c.spells.push(new Spell({name:'fireball'}));
  c.spells.push(new Spell({name:'frozenball'}));
  u.characters.push(c);

  u.save(function(e, s) {
    User.find({username:'foo'}, function(err, success) {
      console.error(err);
      console.log(success);
    });
  });
});
```

**Console output**

```
null
[ { username: 'foo',
    _id: 4fda2c77faa9aa5c68000003,
    created: Thu, 14 Jun 2012 18:24:55 GMT,
    characters: [ undefined ] } ]
```

It looks like the User document is correctly saved and retrieved by mongoose. But, associated embedded documents are **undefined**.

I wanted to be sure that my document is saved, so I've directly asked to mongodb :

```
$ mongo mygame
> db.users.find({username:'foo'})
{
    "username" : "foo",
    "_id" : ObjectId("4fda2c77faa9aa5c68000003"),
    "created" : ISODate("2012-06-14T18:24:55.982Z"),
    "characters" : [
        {
            "name" : "bar",
            "_id" : ObjectId("4fda2c77faa9aa5c68000004"),
            "created" : ISODate("2012-06-14T18:24:55.986Z"),
            "spells" : [
                {
                    "name" : "fireball",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("4fda2c77faa9aa5c68000005"),
                    "created" : ISODate("2012-06-14T18:24:55.987Z")
                },
                {
                    "name" : "frozenball",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("4fda2c77faa9aa5c68000007"),
                    "created" : ISODate("2012-06-14T18:24:55.990Z")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, my documents seems to be correctly stored to mongodb, but I'm unable to retrieve whose who are embedded with mongoose.

I've also tried without the nested embedded Spell document, wich produce the exact same problem.

**EDIT**

@pat You are right. If I put all the Schemas directly in the same file (the main app.js for exemple) with the right order, it works.

The fact is, I would like to keep each models in separate files as much as possible (they are gonna grow a lot).

For exemple, my User model is contained in a file called models/user.js, and *should* be accessible using `module.exports` as above.

But, when I try to link my model to mongoose in an another file : `mongoose.model('User', require('./models/user'));` the mongoose find method returns undefined embedded documents.

Do you have any ideas on how to properly keep my mongoose models on separate files ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user schema file should first require the CharacterSchema at the top, then pass it in:

```
var CharacterSchema = require('./character');

var User = module.exports = new Schema({
      username: { type: String }
    , characters: [CharacterSchema]
    , created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Likewise, the CharacterSchema file should first require the SpellSchema at the top, then pass it:

```
var SpellSchema = require('./spell');
var CharacterSchema = module.exports = new Schema({ spells: [SpellSchema] })
```

This will retain their order.

Note: subdocs are not really needed to be models, since models are mapped to collections, but as long as you are not calling `save` directly on your subdocs they won't get saved to a separate collection in the db.

Comment: Thanks. My problems came from a dependency issue as well as a bad files structure. I've finally ended by joining my models by ObjectIds instead of embedded documents which seems to better fit my needs.

Answer (score 1):

The User schema needs to be declared *after* Character and Spell, I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helped. But I would like to keep the models on separate files, I've edited my question.